# Using Auth middleware on specific routes effieciently Node.js/Express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes, middleware

I'm building a WEB app, the backend with Node.js and Express.
I've built an authentication middleware which detecting if user is logged-in with jwt, I want some routes to use it (protected) and some don't (public) but repeating it at every route seems too robust and old fashioned. for example this is my routes.js :

```
import express from "express";
import authenticateUser from "../../Middlewares/auth.js";
import controller from "./controller.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/searchFor/:term", controller.searchFor);

router.get("/myList", authenticateUser, controller.getMyList);
router
  .route("/myList/:id")
  .get(authenticateUser, controller.isInList)
  .post(authenticateUser, controller.addToList)
  .delete(authenticateUser, controller.removeFromList);
```

The 'searchFor' route is public so I don't want the auth middleware will operate there and because of that I didn't use router.use(authenticateUser).

I thought i could do something like that:

```
router
 .route("/myList/:id", authenticateUser)
 .get(controller.isInList)
 .post(controller.addToList)
 .delete(controller.removeFromList);
```

this way I don't repeat the auth middleware each time, but it's not working so I returned to the first option. Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.all` method of the router to apply middleware to all the routes. Something like that should work:

```
router
 .route("/myList/:id")
 .all(authenticateUser)
 .get(controller.isInList)
 .post(controller.addToList)
 .delete(controller.removeFromList);
```

Check the docs here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route

When your app grows and you have a lot of routes, you can create some sort of configuration object, where you can easily just define new routes and set whether they're public or not. Then, have code that will iterate through the whole object and call appropriate router methods to configure your router.

Here's what it could look like (I haven't checked or tested this code, though):

```
const routesConfiguration = [
    {
        path: "/myList/:id", public: false, methods: [ 
            { method: "get", controller: controller.isInList },
            { method: "post", controller: controller.addToList }]
    },
    {
        path: "/searchFor/:term", public: true, methods: [
            { method: "get", controller: controller.searchFor }
        ]
    }
];

routesConfiguration.forEach(route => {

    router.route(route.path);

    if (route.public) {
        router.all(authenticateUser);
    }
    
    route.methods.forEach(routeMethod => {
        if (routeMethod.method === "get") {
           router.get(routerMethod.controller);
        }
        if (routeMethod.method === "post") {
           router.post(routerMethod.controller);
        }
    });
});
```

With a code like the above you can then just add new entries to the `routesConfiguration` list.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
docs was helpful as well - I have created a authRouter and public router so the auth is using authenticate middleware and rest is the same.

Can you ellaborate about the config file (or give me a source to learn from)?

Comment: I added an example to the answer, what such a configuration handling could look like.